# Missing "dnspython" error for django + gninx + gunicorn app, even after installing it to the correct virtual environment

Tags: django, pymongo, dnspython

Getting the following Error:

```
The "dnspython" module must be installed to use mongodb+srv:// URIs
```

Exception location:

```
../python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py, line 428, in parse_uri
```

When trying to use pymongo with django app. I tried to install dnspython with pip3 to the correct virtual environment but still got the error.

I also tried to re-start gninx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved the problem was simply to re-start the gunicorn service file.